# Overriding multiple inherited templated functions with specialized versions

Tags: c++, templates, overriding, multiple-inheritance, specialization

Okay, sample code first; this is my attempt at communicating what it is that I'm trying to do, although it doesn't compile:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void my_callback() = 0;
};

class Derived1
    : public Base<int>
    , public Base<float>
{
public:
    void my_callback<int>()
    {
        cout << "Int callback for Derived1.\n";
    }
    void my_callback<float>()
    {
        cout << "Float callback for Derived\n";
    }
};

class Derived2
    : public Base<int>
    , public Base<float>
{

public:
    void my_callback<int>()
    {
        cout << "Int callback for Derived2.\n";
    }
    void my_callback<float>()
    {
        cout << "Float callback for Derived2\n";
    }

};

int main()
{
    {
        Derived1 d;
        Base<int> * i_p = d;
        Base<float> * i_f = d;

        i_p->my_callback();
        i_f->my_callback();
    }
    {
        Derived2 d;
        Base<int> * i_p = d;
        Base<float> * i_f = d;

        i_p->my_callback();
        i_f->my_callback();
    }

    //Desired output:
    // Int callback for Derived1.
    // Float callback for Derived1
    // Int callback for Derived2.
    // Float callback for Derived2
    system("Pause");
}
```

So, what I'm trying to do is to make a sort of wrapper class to inherit from that will automatically connect the derived class to various callback lists; it needs to connect a specific instance of the derived class to the list, and I want the "user" to have / get to make the callback functions as part of making the derived class, as you can see.

It seems like this should be able to work, although I may need to use a different syntax. If it can't work, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Similar questions (but without templates): https://stackoverflow.com/q/5481356/94687 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/3150310/94687

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can make this work:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Base
{
public:
  virtual void my_callback() = 0;
};

class Derived1 : public Base<int>, public Base<float>
{
public:
  void Base<int>::my_callback() {
    cout << "Int callback for Derived1.\n";
  }
  void Base<float>::my_callback() {
    cout << "Float callback for Derived\n";
  }
};

class Derived2 : public Base<int>, public Base<float>
{
public:
  void Base<int>::my_callback() {
    cout << "Int callback for Derived2.\n";
  }
  void Base<float>::my_callback() {
    cout << "Float callback for Derived2\n";
  }
};

int main()
{
  {
    Derived1 d;
    Base<int> * i_p = &d;
    Base<float> * i_f = &d;
    i_p->my_callback();
    i_f->my_callback();
  }
  {
    Derived2 d;
    Base<int> * i_p = &d;
    Base<float> * i_f = &d;
    i_p->my_callback();
    i_f->my_callback();
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Int callback for Derived1.
Float callback for Derived
Int callback for Derived2.
Float callback for Derived2
```

Comment: This does not compile (gcc). Your declarations of Derived::my_callback can not work like that.

Comment: This works for me; of note, I am using Visual Studio 2008, which I know has some features that aren't standard. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, this is a side-effect of support for explicit interface implementation.  You'll be okay as long as you can stick with MSVC.

Comment: Thanks but it'd prefer to have standard way to do this. Still thinking how to get this done in standard manner.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is *not possible*.

You could add template specializations, though I do not know if this really helps:

```
template <class T>
class Base {
public:
  virtual void my_callback() = 0;
};

template <>
class Base<int> {
public:
  virtual void my_callback() {
    cout << "Base<int>::my_callback()\n";
  }
};

template <>
class Base<float> {
public:
  virtual void my_callback() {
    cout << "Base<float>::my_callback()\n";
  }
};

class Derived1 : public Base<int>, public Base<float> {
public:
  // NOTE: no my_callback() implementation here
};

class Derived2 : public Base<int>, public Base<float> {
public:
  virtual void my_callback() {
    cout << "Derived2::my_callback()\n";
  }
};


int main()
{
  {
    Derived1 d;
    Base<int> * i_p = &d;
    Base<float> * i_f = &d;
    i_p->my_callback();
    i_f->my_callback();
  }
  {
    Derived2 d;
    Base<int> * i_p = &d;
    Base<float> * i_f = &d;
    i_p->my_callback();
    i_f->my_callback();
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Base<int>::my_callback()
Base<float>::my_callback()
Derived2::my_callback()
Derived2::my_callback()
```

Let me try to explain why:

```
Derived1 d;
Base<int> * i_p = &d;
Base<float> * i_f = &d;

// will check the vtable, and will call
//  either Derived1::my_callback
//  OR Base<int>::my_callback
i_p->my_callback();

// will check the vtable, and will call
//  either Derived1::my_callback
//  OR Base<float>::my_callback
i_f->my_callback();
```

Though through the vtable there are two versions of my_callback() in class Derived1, you CAN NOT override either of them, you can only override both at once (like Derived2 does in the example)!

You should just provide two methods "my_callback1()" and "my_callback2()".

Answer (score 0):

Whether using a template class or a non-template one, this can be done by using helper classes in [this style](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2005142/908336) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3150358/908336).

(It seems this is the only portable solution if you do not plan to use Microsoft specific qualified names.)

Answer (score -1):

Doesn't *virtuality* associated with *template* raises an alarm in your head ? ;)

You have to choose your side, either the static, or the dynamic one.

Comment: "_Doesn't virtuality associated with template raises an alarm in your head ?_" Why would it?