# C++ virtual override functions with same name

Tags: c++, virtual, overriding, diamond-problem

I have something like that (simplified)

```
class A
{
  public:
    virtual void Function () = 0;
};

class B
{
  public:
    virtual void Function () = 0;
};

class Impl : public A , public B
{
  public:
        ????
};
```

How can I implement the Function () for A and the Function() for B ?
Visual C++ lets you only define the specific function inline (i.e. not in the cpp file),
but I suppose it's an extension. GCC complains about this.
Is there a standard C++ way to tell the compiler which function I want to override?

(visual c++ 2008)

```
class Impl : public A , public B
{
  public:
     void A::Function () {  cout << "A::Function" << endl; }
     void B::Function () {  cout << "B::Function" << endl; }
};
```

Thank you!

Comment: also, I've finally realized how QueryInterface happens to work when implementing multiple COM interfaces! :)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You cannot use qualified names there. I you write `void Function() { ... }` you are overriding *both* functions. Herb Sutter shows [how it can be solved](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/039.htm).

Another option is to rename those functions, because apparently they do something different (otherwise i don't see the problem of overriding *both* with identical behavior).

Answer (score 5):

I can suggest another way to resolve this issue. You can add wrapper `Typed` which changes `Function` signature by adding dummy parameter. Thus you can distinguish methods in your implementation.

```
class A {
public:
  virtual void Function() = 0;
  virtual ~A() = default;
};

class B {
public:
  virtual void Function() = 0;
  virtual ~B() = default;
};

template<typename T>
class Typed : public T {
public:
  virtual void Function(T* dummy) = 0;
  void Function() override {
    Function(nullptr);
  }
};

class Impl : public Typed<A>, public Typed<B> {
public:
  void Function(A* dummy) override {
    std::cerr << "implements A::Function()" << std::endl;
  }
  void Function(B* dummy) override {
    std::cerr << "implements B::Function()" << std::endl;
  }
};
```

The benefit of such solution is that all implementation are placed in one class.

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, try

```
struct Impl_A : A
{ 
     void Function () {  cout << "A::Function" << endl; } 
}; 


struct Impl_B : B
{
    void Function () { cout << "B::function" << endl; }
};

struct Impl : Impl_A, Impl_B {};
```

Answer (score -1):

If A and B are interfaces, then I would use virtual derivation to "join" them (make them overlap). If you need different implementations for your `Function` if called through a pointer to `A` or to `B` then I would strongly recommend to choose another design. That will hurt otherwise.

`Impl` "derives from" `A` and `B` means `Impl` "is a" `A` and `B`. I suppose you do not mean it.

`Impl` "implements interface" `A` and `B` means `Impl` "behaves like" `A` and `B`. then same interface should mean the same behavior.

In both cases having a different behavior according to the type of pointer used would be "schizophrenic" and is for sure a situation to avoid.

Comment: there is no diamond here. Only name clash. A and B could come from different libraries.

Comment: @Alex yes, it was bad terminology, namespace clash is appropriate.

Comment: How would virtual derivation help here?