# How to implement two interfaces having the same function

Tags: c++, interface, abstract-class, implementation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ virtual override functions with same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150310/c-virtual-override-functions-with-same-name)

I have class which must implement two interfaces with the same method. For example:

```
class IInterface1
{
public:
    virtual void Method() = 0;
};

class IInterface2
{
public:
    virtual void Method() = 0;
};

class Implementation : public IInterface1, IInterface2
{
    // ???
};
```

Is this possible? If yes, what is exact syntax to use in .h and in .cpp file.

Note. I can do this with two helper classes implementing IInterface1 and IInterface2. But I am curious whether it is possible to do directly.