# Overriding Qualified Virtual Methods

Tags: c++, virtual-functions, ambiguity

I have C++ class with multiple parents; each parent defines a function with a common name but a different purpose:

```
class BaseA
{
    virtual void myFunc();  // does some task
};
class BaseB
{
    virtual void myFunc();  // does some other task
};
class Derived : public BaseA, public BaseB;
```

If that was it, I would have no problem - I could resolve the ambiguity it with a **using** statement, and I could choose which one to call using the base class names and the scope resolution operator.

Unfortunately, the derived class needs to override them both:

```
class Derived : public BaseA, public BaseB
{
    virtual void BaseA::myFunc(); // Derived needs to change the way both tasks are done
    virtual void BaseB::myFunc();
}
```

This doesn't work, not because it introduces a new ambiguity (although it may), but because

> "error C3240: 'myFunc' : must be a non-overloaded abstract member function of 'BaseA'"
>
> "error C2838: illegal qualified name in member declaration"

Under different circumstances I might just rename the methods, or make them pure virtual as the compiler suggests.  However, the class hierarchy structure and a number of external issues make the first option **extremely** difficult, and the second impossible.

Does anyone have a suggestion?  Why are qualifiers only allowed for pure virtual methods?  Is there any way to simultaneously override virtual methods and resolve ambiguities?

Comment: You could also override the behaviours in separate classes: `DerivedA : public BaseA`, `DerivedB : public BaseB`, and then `Derived : public DerivedA, public DerivedB`. This doesn't solve the ambiguity problem, though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Microsoft allows that syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ksek8777.aspx) (it's available beginning in Visual C++ 2005).  [They also introduced a new, more powerful syntax for managed code only](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw0bbh51.aspx).

Neither one was included in C++0x.

See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2108.html

---

I think this is a workaround:

```
class BaseA
{
protected:
    virtual void myFunc();  // does some task
};
class BaseB
{
protected:
    virtual void myFunc();  // does some other task
};
class ShimA : virtual BaseA
{
    virtual void myFunc() { myFuncA(); }
protected:
    virtual void myFuncA() { BaseA::myFunc(); }
};
class ShimB : virtual BaseB
{
    virtual void myFunc() { myFuncB(); }
protected:
    virtual void myFuncB() { BaseB::myFunc(); }
};
class Derived : public virtual BaseA, public virtual BaseB, protected ShimA, protected ShimB
{
     virtual void myFuncA() {}
     virtual void myFuncB() {}
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the info on the MS syntax; unfortunately it only works with abstract base classes (note the "__interface" keyword in their example).

Comment: @John: The managed variant works for virtual methods inherited from base classes.  Anyway, take a look at my edit, I think this should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks again.  Your suggestion would work, but the details of my situation prevent me from using it.  Basically, I'm writing a class definition for some reverse-engineered code and I literally can't change the inheritance structure or the composition of the virtual function table (or use managed C++, obviously)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a composition object.

```
class Derived : public BaseB {        
    struct temp : public BaseA {
        virtual void myFunc() {
             d->BaseAMyFunc();
        }
        Derived* d;
    };
    temp t;
public:
    Derived() {
        t.d = this;
    }
    operator BaseA&() { return temp; }
    operator const BaseA&() const { return temp; }
    void myFunc(); // refers to BaseB::myFunc()
    void BaseAMyFunc(); // called when BaseA::myFunc() is called.
}
```

This isn't especially neat and it's somewhat restricted, but it does work some circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the big issues with [multiple inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance).  There are always issues when you have multiple functions of the same name being inherited to determine which one is supposed to be overridden see [The Diamond Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem).  You cannot override both as the function syntax (function name and operators) must be unique.

Answer (score 0):

I realise that this question is old, but it's had a lot of views and there is a clean way to solve this if you are the author of the interfaces.

Many people believe that virtual interfaces should have public non-virtual functions that defer to private virtual functions internally (I agree with them). This has a few advantages, one of them being that non-virtual names can have distinct meanings since they are more strongly bound to the interface:

```
struct BaseA
{
  virtual ~BaseA() = default;

  void func() 
  {
    handle_a_func();
  }

private:
  virtual void handle_a_func() = 0;
};

struct BaseB 
{
  virtual ~BaseB() = default;

  int func() const  // note the different signature and return type
  {
    handle_b_func();
  }

private:
  virtual int handle_b_func() const = 0;
};

// now provide an implementation

struct ABImpl : public BaseA, public BaseB
{
  ABImpl() {}

private:
  void handle_a_func() override final 
  {
    // alter some state
  }

  int handle_b_func() const override final
  {
    return _x;
  }

  int _x = 0;
};        

// now use the class
auto ab = make_shared<ABImpl>();

auto a = static_pointer_cast<BaseA>(ab);
auto b = static_pointer_cast<const BaseB>(ab);

a->func();  // uses A's mutable interface
auto x = b->func();  // uses B's const interface
```

Another advantage of this approach is that base class implementations can manage things like mutexes and sentinels on behalf of the derived functions, for example:

```
struct base {

  void do() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(_m);
    handle_do();
  }

private:
  virtual void handle_do() = 0;

  std::mutex _m;
};
```

Yet another advantage is that some useful free-function operators need only be defined once for the entire class hierarchy:

```
struct base
{
  void write_to(std::ostream& os) const {
    // lock a mutex here?
    handle_write(os);
  private:
    virtual void handle_write(std::ostream& os) const {
      os << "write base class info here\n";
    }
};

inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const base& b) {
  b.write_to(os);
  return os;
}

struct derived : base {
private:
  virtual void handle_write(std::ostream& os) const override {
    base::handle_write(os);  // handle base class implementation
    std::cout << "write relevant data here. We could still be overridden safely\n";
  }
};

// write any derived class like this:
auto b = unique_ptr<base> { new derived() };
cout << "here is a kind-of b:\n" << *b << endl;
```